# When using SSMS Solution Explorer, Is it possible to drag-and-drop a file from the Miscellaneous Folder to a Project Folder as a linked file?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, ssms-2012

[image: My Solution]
See attached image.

I am using SQL Server Management Studio 2012. 
I want to be able to drag-and-drop SQLQuery2.sql from the Miscellaneous Folder to "My Project"->"Queries" Folder without physically placing the file in the "My Project" file location.  (I know this is possible by right-clicking on "My Project" and selecting "Add Existing Item" and then selecting the file and clicking on the down-arrow of the Add button, and selecting "Add As Link".)  I have tried holding down "Ctrl-Shift" while dragging but that doesn't work. Any ideas? Thanks